127.0.0.1 and localhost driving me nuts, help appreciated
i am using supabase with nextjs app router. starting supabase locally uses 127.0.0.1

API URL: http://127.0.0.1:54321
GraphQL URL: http://127.0.0.1:54321/graphql/v1
S3 Storage URL: http://127.0.0.1:54321/storage/v1/s3
DB URL: postgresql://postgres:postgres@127.0.0.1:54322/postgres
Studio URL: http://127.0.0.1:54323
Inbucket URL: http://127.0.0.1:54324

so i set
"dev": "next dev --hostname 127.0.0.1",
at package.json. auth works and its all good.
Now the issue comes when i try learning docker
Dockerfile:
`FROM node:18-alpine AS base 
FROM base AS dev
WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies
COPY package.json yarn.lock* package-lock.json* pnpm-lock.yaml* ./
RUN \
    if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn install; \
    elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm install; \
    elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then corepack enable pnpm && pnpm install; \
    else echo "Lockfile not found." && exit 1; \
    fi

# Copy the rest of the application code
COPY . .

# Expose the port Next.js is running on
EXPOSE 3000

# Start the Next.js development server
CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]`


// docker-compose.yml
version: "3"

services:
  open-math-prep-dev:
    build:
      context: ../../
      dockerfile: docker/dev/Dockerfile
      target: dev
    image: open-math-prep-dev
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      - WATCHPACK_POLLING=true
    volumes:
        - ../../:/app
        - /app/node_modules
        - /app/.next

When i spin up the container, i end up with zero error logs and just 127.0.0.1 didnt send any data. If i get rid of --hostname and change everything to use localhost, my google auth redirect ends up in Bad Request, because it takes me to 127.0.0.1:54321/auth/callback since that is the api url from npx supabase start
Thanks alot for any help!
set back localhost, set back 127.0.0.1

Have you tried using different version of node? I had once a similar problem and it all resolved by just using the latest version of node.

unfortunately didnt work =( tried setting FROM node:20-alpine and still getting 127.0.0.1 didnt send any data when i go there

The IPv4 address 127.0.0.1 (and the corresponding IPv6 address ::1, and the canonical DNS name localhost) means "the current network context", but that's at least two different things depending on your setup:

The open-math-prep-dev container believes it is a "localhost" different from everything else;
The system running the end user's browser is a different "localhost";
If the browser and the Docker daemon aren't on the same machine, the host system running Docker is a different "localhost";
If you're using Docker Desktop or another similar VM-based solution, there's a Linux VM that is a different "localhost";
If you have other containers (like a database) in your setup, these are different "localhost"s.

A process running in a container always needs to listen on 0.0.0.0, not 127.0.0.1.  If you set the process to listen on 127.0.0.1 then it only accepts connections from its own "localhost", and it's unreachable from outside its own container (including other containers and the current host system).  You need to remove the --hostname 127.0.0.1 option, and depending on the specific default setup of the dev server you may need to add --hostname 0.0.0.0 in its place.  (Also see for example running a vite dev server inside a docker container; that particular setup needs npm run dev -- --host.)
With that setup, then, the ports: ['3000:3000'] block will cause port 3000 on the host machine to forward to port 3000 in the container.  (The second port number must match what the container process is listening on, the two port numbers do not need to match.)  From your browser you'd connect to http://host.example.com:3000/, using the host machine's DNS name.  You can use http://localhost:3000/ if the browser and the Docker daemon are running on the same system.

Hi there thanks for reply, getting rid of the --hostname will allow me to see the page when i spin up the container. However, i end up unable to use supabase google auth locally, since it redirects to 127.0.0.1 and i end up with Bad Request

I think its because normally my docker compose file doesnt spin up the supabase service too. so what im doing is spinning up my nextjs container, then doing npx supabase start to start another container. However, my nextjs is not able to communicate with the separate supabase container. Would be looking into this, but any help is appreciated!

That seems like you need to add the second container into your Compose file?  (It could build: the same image and override the command:, but it sounds like the database shouldn't share code with your application at all.)
